# How do I restrict Chrome with Screen Time?

Tags: macos, ios, google-chrome, screen-time

I want to disable Chrome after 11pm at night. However since the last iOS update I can’t seem to restrict Chrome anymore. The apps are just missing from the "Always Allowed" screen.

How can you limit access to the internet on an iOS device to certain hours? It feels like a bug to only be able to limit every other app on your phone!

[image]

Comment: You can set downtime limits in iOS’ screen time settings. Downtime will not block Safari/Chrome but it’ll prompt you to enter screen time passcode for every individual website, so hopefully that will discourage you using the web. You can also set other apps to be allowed during downtime (Safari being one notable app you can’t exempt?). Let me know if that helps!

Comment: No, that's not what I need. I need unlimited access to the internet until after 11pm. This was a feature in iOS 13 :(

Comment: You can set the downtime limit to be say 11pm-7am (or whenever you wake up). That way only the "Always Allowed" apps will be available between those times and Safari will essentially prompt you to enter a screentime passcode for literally every single website during that time period? Outside of that time, you will have free-rein to use all apps including Safari. Does this help?

Comment: @AVelj No, that's the problem. Chrome and Safari no longer appear in the "Always Allowed" screen in settings.

Comment: Safari has never been in the always allowed options at least since iOS 12. Not sure about chrome because i don’t use it. But this shouldn’t be a problem if you are setting screen time at night to avoid using the internet?

Comment: @AVelj Both Safari and Chrome were added in iOS 13.

Comment: I have checked an iOS 13 device and can confirm Safari was not in the "always allowed" list, but Chrome was in this list. I believe Google said they will make Chrome work with screen time in a future update. Other than the Chrome problem, the "always allowed" app list allows you to use the always allowed apps during a designated "downtime" period (say between 11pm-7am) without prompting for a screentime passcode. So not having Safari in this list means you will be prompted to enter a passcode for every website you visit during the downtime period. This is kind of what you want, right?

Comment: Because it will literally force you to enter a passcode for every single website during this downtime period making the web practically unusable. BUT this only works for Safari, whereas for other web browsers (apart from Chrome), it'll prompt you to enter a passcode once to use the web browser app and then you can visit as many websites as you want without needing to enter a passcode for every site like Safari does. Again, this doesn't really fix your issue if you're using Chrome, but Google did say they intend to integrate it in a future update. So for the interim, maybe delete chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution! It's not perfect, but I've been testing it and it just about works:

1. In Chrome, on the device in question, go to this address: chrome://flags/
2. Then search for "screentime" (all one word).
3. You should see: **Enables ScreenTime Integration**
4. Switch this to ENABLED.

It's a bit glitchy, but it works. It locks Chrome in the way you'd expect it to.

In the meantime, tell the developers how important this is to you here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1162695

It seems the longterm plan might be for Chrome to fully support Screen Time (like Safari does), allowing users to manually allow access to specific websites during Downtime.

More information: https://www.chromestory.com/2020/09/chrome-ios-screen-time/

It's unclear when this feature will be added however.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my findings to this. It seems that chrome is not visible as an app to set screen time for when setting the child’s limit from the parent phone. However when I opened screen time on my kid’s iPad, I could enable chrome screen time rules there.
PS: I did enable screen time flags in chrome as posted above as well.